# DDD: Aggregates and sub-aggregates

Tags: language-agnostic, doctrine-orm, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I have a quite complex aggregate, with aggregate root `Order`. It contains entities (eg. `OrderItem`) which are meaningless outside an aggregate. But there are also entities that are supposed to be part of this aggregate, but also do make sense outside this aggregate (eg. `ShippingMethod` or `Invoice`).

Is it right to have a repository for this complex aggregate (loading whole aggregate by root's id) and also have CRUD repository for managing possible shipping methods and another repository for listing invoices?

More generally, is it possible in DDD to have an aggregate, which is part of another aggregate?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611635/reference-another-aggregate-root-inside-another-aggregate-root/17620246#17620246

Comment: Having just a value object representing data from `ShippingMethod` looks like a good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can consider "an aggregate, which is part of another aggregate" as "an aggregate holds another aggregate's reference".

For example

```
public class Order {
    private Invoice invoice;
}

<class name="Order" table="T_ORDER">
    <one-to-one name="invoice" column="INVOICE_ID" />
</class>
```

If both Order and Invoice are aggregates in this context, I'll have a OrderRepository and a InvoiceRepository.You can retrieve an Order using

```
orderRepository.findBy(orderId)
```

And you can retrieve an Invoice using

```
invoiceRepository.findBy(invoiceId)
```

or

```
Order order = orderRepository.findBy(orderId);
Invoice invoice = order.getInvoice();
```

And there is famous article about how to design aggregates(http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/) which suggests realizing this relationships using Identity reference.

```
public Class Order {
    private InvoiceId invoiceId;
}

<class name="Order" table="T_ORDER">
    <component name="invoiceId">
        <property name="value" column="INVOICE_ID" />
    </component>
</class>
```

You can retrieve an Order using

```
orderRepository.findBy(orderId)
```

And you can retrieve an Invoice using

```
invoiceRepository.findBy(invoiceId)
```

or

```
Order order = orderRepository.findBy(orderId);
Invoice invoice = invoiceRepository.findBy(order.getInvoiceId());
```

Comment: How to implement this using ORM (I'm using php and doctrine)? Isn't having a referencing id directly in entity considered as an antipattern?

Comment: I'm not familiar with php and doctrine. But it could be implemented using regular one-to-one mapping with Hibernate in Java(In Aggregate reference Aggregate case). I'm not sure is referencing id an anti-pattern, is there some articles or resources that discuss this?

Comment: Doctrine is heavily inspired by Hibernate. I mean having an integer attribute like invoiceId in an entity is an antipattern, according to http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/best-practices.html#don-t-map-foreign-keys-to-fields-in-an-entity.

Edit: Now I see you meant not an integer, but a value object containing just id.

Comment: The referencing id is a value object. You would now issue two queries instead of navigating through `Order` to `Orderitems`.

Comment: But I'd like to have Order.invoice_id in db as a foreign key because of easier reporting. Is there way to map it to VO in domain model and to related entity in reporting model? Or should I separate domain entities and persistance entities (they would be almost the same)?

Comment: @MatějKoubík Answer updated for adding hibernate mapping example. You'd better not seperate domain models and persistence objects, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650073/orm-how-to-deal-with-the-correspondence-between-domain-object-and-persistent-o.

Comment: But then I couln't use HQL for reporting, because invoice_id is an integer, not a reference to Invoice entity. Or?

Comment: Honestly, I have the same question if adopting the identity reference case. I'm reading Vernon's article, hope to find some clue.